# Python data validation for words

Tags: python

Hello i have a problem making my validation that forces the user to enter 5 words , currently if they enter a space they can go trough also. Here is my code:

```
cntr = 0 
for x in range(len(this.val)): 
    if this.val[x]. == ' ' and not this.val[x-1] == ' ' and x != 0: 
        cntr = cntr + 1

if cntr lt 4: 
    error(res.Q3error)
```

Comment: what is `this.val`? your code is not valid python

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in order to get answer, please read and follow this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
words = sentence.split()
if len(words) == 5:
   print('good')
```

Or perhaps add a "is_word" test to apply to "words" using an all() - in case you want to reject numbers or something.